# free sms gateway for .Net client

Tags: c#, asp.net, sms, sms-gateway

Does anyone know any good free sms gateway which can be accessed using the C# client?

I also need some C# sample wrappers for interacting with the sms gateway for sending and receiving the SMSs.

Thanks in advance.
S.

Comment: Ive done some of my own searching in the past, and im curious about this myself

Comment: As far as "free" goes, nothing reliable (No surprise there) but there are some very cheap options, as listed bellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at these gateways:

http://www.intellisoftware.co.uk/sms-gateway/

http://www.ozekisms.com/

http://www.redoxygen.com/developers/c-sharp/

Comment: he asked for a free gateway, all those companies you posted there website URL are not free!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use https://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-sms-gateway/16935285

From what I understand, it's a full SMS Gateway you can install in your WordPress website and use from any other website with CURL. The SMS messages are sent by Android devices you connect to your WordPress website.